# How do I add and display attributes in an element?

Tags: xml, vb.net

Currently my function is only displaying elements but not their attributes. I am not sure how to add attributes to the elements. I can view all the elements in debug mode but the elements that need to have attributes do not have them. 
For example
I would like to see `<Message MessageType="GetCodeListing" NodeID="1" ReferenceNumber="R-19293" UserID="8304" Source="IntegrationBroker">` but I only see `<Message/>` which means I need to add the attributes to this element. 
How do I do this?

Please note that `<Word ExactMatch='true'>07001G</Word>` the `Word` is a variable and I am not sure how to add it. 
I would like to have output that looks like this:

```
<Transaction ReferenceNumber="CC-Add-Appl-Doc-06292015_05" Source="IntegrationBroker" TransactionType="Multi">
    <DataPropagation>
        <IntraTxn xPath="/TxnResponse/Result[1]/Codes/Code/CodeID" ReplStr="#|CODEID|#"/>
    </DataPropagation>
    <Message MessageType="GetCodeListing" NodeID="1" ReferenceNumber="R-19293" UserID="8304" Source="IntegrationBroker">
        <CodeTypeID>JUS136</CodeTypeID>
        <Search>
            <Word ExactMatch='true'>07001G</Word>
        </Search>
    </Message>
    <Message MessageType="GetJudicialOfficerCode" NodeID="1" ReferenceNumber="R-19293" UserID="8304" Source="IntegrationBroker">
        <CodeID>#|CODEID|#</CodeID>
    </Message>
</Transaction>
```

My function creates a new document and adds elements into it. I am not sure how to add attributes to the elements and that is the help I need.

```
 Function GetJudgeAPI(ByVal astrJudgeId As String) As XmlDocument
    Dim objXmlOutPutDoc As XmlDocument
    Dim objXmlTransactionDoc As XmlDocument

    'Create Transaction message
    objXmlTransactionDoc = New XmlDocument
    objXmlTransactionDoc.AppendChild(objXmlTransactionDoc.CreateElement("Transaction"))
    objXmlTransactionDoc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("ReferenceNumber", System.Guid.NewGuid.ToString)
    objXmlTransactionDoc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("Source", "IntegrationBroker")
    objXmlTransactionDoc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("TransactionType", "Get Judge")

    'Add Data Propagation
    objXmlTransactionDoc.SelectSingleNode("Transaction").AppendChild(objXmlTransactionDoc.CreateElement("DataPropagation"))
    objXmlTransactionDoc.SelectSingleNode("Transaction/DataPropagation").AppendChild(objXmlTransactionDoc.CreateElement("IntraTxn"))

    'Add Message
    objXmlTransactionDoc.SelectSingleNode("Transaction").AppendChild(objXmlTransactionDoc.CreateElement("Message"))
    objXmlTransactionDoc.SelectSingleNode("Transaction/Message[1]").AppendChild(objXmlTransactionDoc.CreateElement("CodeTypeID"))
    objXmlTransactionDoc.SelectSingleNode("Transaction/Message[1]/CodeTypeID").InnerText = "JUS136"
    objXmlTransactionDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Transaction/Message[1]").AppendChild(objXmlTransactionDoc.CreateElement("Search"))
    objXmlTransactionDoc.SelectSingleNode("Transaction/Message[1]/Search").AppendChild(objXmlTransactionDoc.CreateElement("Word"))
    'Message 2
    objXmlTransactionDoc.SelectSingleNode("Transaction").AppendChild(objXmlTransactionDoc.CreateElement("Message"))
    objXmlTransactionDoc.SelectSingleNode("Transaction/Message[2]").AppendChild(objXmlTransactionDoc.CreateElement("CodeID"))
    objXmlTransactionDoc.SelectSingleNode("Transaction/Message[2]/CodeID").InnerText = "#|CODEID|#"

End Function
```

Comment: You are returning `objXmlOutPutDoc`, but that doesn't seem to ever be assigned.  Try returning `objXmlTransactionDoc`?  You are adding attributes to the `<Transaction>` element, so what is your question?

Comment: My question is right now I can view in debug mode all the elements added to the ` objXmlTransactionDoc = New XmlDocument`, however the elements with attributes do not have those attribute values in them. so how do I add the attributes to the elements so they can be displayed?

Comment: If I run your code (as-is, except returning `objXmlTransactionDoc`), the `Transaction` element has attributes and values - `<Transaction ReferenceNumber="9f9dc0a1-1d1e-420e-b413-c133bf7e46a0" Source="IntegrationBroker" TransactionType="Get Judge">`, so don't you just need to use the same method (`.SetAttribute(name, value)`) to add attributes to the other elements?  I don't see any code that even attempts to add attributes for the other elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to switch to the [`System.Xml.Linq`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) classes ([LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)) and [XML Literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384629.aspx):

```vb
Dim word As String = "07001G"
Dim xml As XElement =
<Transaction ReferenceNumber=<%= Guid.NewGuid().ToString() %> Source="IntegrationBroker" TransactionType="Multi">
    <DataPropagation>
        <IntraTxn xPath="/TxnResponse/Result[1]/Codes/Code/CodeID" ReplStr="#|CODEID|#"/>
    </DataPropagation>
    <Message MessageType="GetCodeListing" NodeID="1" ReferenceNumber="R-19293" UserID="8304" Source="IntegrationBroker">
        <CodeTypeID>JUS136</CodeTypeID>
        <Search>
            <Word ExactMatch="true"><%= word %></Word>
        </Search>
    </Message>
    <Message MessageType="GetJudicialOfficerCode" NodeID="1" ReferenceNumber="R-19293" UserID="8304" Source="IntegrationBroker">
        <CodeID>#|CODEID|#</CodeID>
    </Message>
</Transaction>
```

As you can see, you can embed expressions in the XML literal, using `<%= ... %>` syntax, to do variable substitution, as used above for the `ReferenceNumber` attribute value and and the `Word` element value.  It makes dealing with XML in VB.NET so much nicer (at least to me, I suppose others may not like the embedding of XML in the code!).

Comment: Mark I am not able to use Linq. This is why I am using `objXmlTransactionDoc = New XmlDocument`. All elements are visible in debug mode but none of the elements that have attributes get their attributes added or displayed. I am not sure how to add the attributes to the elements.